# I need a SAT question generator (Site/software)

Tags: reference-request, online-resources

I'm teaching math for a SAT prep school. Whenever I give a class I have to transcript the questions on latex to produce a Worksheet to use with my students. I'm looking for a software or a site to create quickly math exams with SAT sample questions.

An example: suppose I want to make a math quiz about heart of Algebra which is one of the four subjects of the math test. I also want this test being solved with calculator, then I click in the software: math test, calculator questions, and heart of Algebra. Afterwards a PDF file is generated.

Does this exist?

Answer (score 2):

You should check out https://www.lem.ma/prep (full disclosure I work for them); we offer a wealth of problems created by an award-winning educator (B.S. Physics from Princeton, Ph.D. Applied Mathematics from MIT).

Our platform has a technology stack that puts us above all other online services:

- refreshable problems (www.lem.ma/K9) (problems that can refresh with different numbers, but keep the same form)
- dynamic figures (www.lem.ma/y4)
- cross-linked content (www.lem.ma/EQ)
- and much more!

We've launched our Alpha product and we're absolutely free until Sept. 16th.

If you have any questions about our product, a partnership, etc. contact me at axel@lem.ma!